# Terraform - The true and false result expressions must have consistent types

Tags: terraform

I am setting a value of the locals based on variable passed.

If variable is set, I want to have a map output, if not, just a list.

Implementing the code below I get error `The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The │ 'true' value includes object attribute "am", which is absent in the 'false' │ value.`

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
module "many_names" {
 ...
  optional_descr = {
    storage_account = ["am", "sn"]
  }
 ...

module "one_name" {
 ...
# not setting optional_descr
 ...
```

Module code:

```
locals {
  prefix = join("-", var.prefix)
  suffix = join("-", var.suffix)
  az = {
   ...
    storage_account = merge(
      var.optional_descr.storage_account != null ?
      { for key in var.optional_descr.storage_account :
        "${key}" => {
          name        = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "${key}", "stct", local.suffix])), 0, 63)
          name_unique = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "${key}", "stct", local.suffix_unique])), 0, 63)
          dashes      = true
          slug        = "stct"
          min_length  = 3
          max_length  = 63
          scope       = "parent"
          regex       = "^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+$"
        }
        } : {
        name        = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "stct", local.suffix])), 0, 63)
        name_unique = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "stct", local.suffix_unique])), 0, 63)
        dashes      = true
        slug        = "stct"
        min_length  = 3
        max_length  = 63
        scope       = "parent"
        regex       = "^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+$"
      }
    )
   ... etc ...
    virtual_network = {
      name        = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "vn", local.suffix])), 0, 64)
      name_unique = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "vn", local.suffix_unique])), 0, 64)
      dashes      = true
      slug        = "vn"
      min_length  = 2
      max_length  = 64
      scope       = "resourceGroup"
      regex       = "^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-._]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]$"
    }
```

Desired use of the module output:
*In Case

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this" {
    name = module.one_name.az.stotrage_account.name
    ...
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "am" {
    name = module.many_names.az.storage_account["am"].name
    ...
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sn" {
    name = module.many_names.az.storage_account["sn"].name
    ...
}
```

As an option, I had `["default']` key applied, so when referencing I used `xxx.storage_container["default"].name` if `optional_descr.storage_account` is not set. But would like to have a bit cleaner outputs.

Comment: Having the `"default"` key seems cleaner to me - that keeps the shape of the data the same. Why do you have a `merge()` call there?

Comment: This is a part of a huge module, which generates names for multiple resources types in Azure. Stripping `"default"` out was the mitigation for not implementing it for all of those types. Only some would support `.optional_descr`. 

Advise for not having `merge()`?

Comment: Regarding `merge()`: if you're not merging anything, just don't have it?

Comment: I don't think I understand how you're using this data structure. The way you've shown it, you would then need to have more conditionals controlling whether to pull out a structure using a key or whether to use the object directly; having a `default` key means you'd always be accessing the object with a key. But mainly I think you need to show more details about how this is all used

Comment: Thanks. Basically, when module is called, it returns a huge object for each resource type for `azurerm provider`. To provision a resource, that module output is used to assign a name. For example: if, as in code example above, `optional_descr` is set, then I will reference those as `"azurerm_storage_account" "am" {  name = module.names.resources.storage_account["am"].name ...}`, `"azurerm_storage_account" "sn" {  name = module.names.resources.storage_account["sn"].name ...}`, otherwise, I want to use `"azurerm_linux_function_app" "this" {  name = module.names.resources.function_app.name ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the error message, Terraform doesn't want one variable to have multiple possible types. However, you can just use two different variables for the two different cases.

Since you will need to know (from the outside) whether the `storage_account` thing is set or not, you can make use of the output differently according to that. Make two different outputs from the module:

1. The keyed mapping of sub-name rules
2. The unkeyed direct name rule

So something like

```
locals {
  prefix = join("-", var.prefix)
  suffix = join("-", var.suffix)
  az = {
   ...
    storage_account_sub = 
      var.optional_descr.storage_account != null ?
      { for key in var.optional_descr.storage_account :
        "${key}" => {
          name        = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "${key}", "stct", local.suffix])), 0, 63)
          name_unique = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "${key}", "stct", local.suffix_unique])), 0, 63)
          dashes      = true
          slug        = "stct"
          min_length  = 3
          max_length  = 63
          scope       = "parent"
          regex       = "^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+$"
        }
      } : null

    storage_account = {
        name        = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "stct", local.suffix])), 0, 63)
        name_unique = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "stct", local.suffix_unique])), 0, 63)
        dashes      = true
        slug        = "stct"
        min_length  = 3
        max_length  = 63
        scope       = "parent"
        regex       = "^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+$"
    }

   ... etc ...
    virtual_network = {
      name        = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "vn", local.suffix])), 0, 64)
      name_unique = substr(join("-", compact([local.prefix, "vn", local.suffix_unique])), 0, 64)
      dashes      = true
      slug        = "vn"
      min_length  = 2
      max_length  = 64
      scope       = "resourceGroup"
      regex       = "^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-._]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]$"
    }
```

Then you can choose which one to use as required:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this" {
    name = module.one_name.az.storage_account.name
    ...
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "am" {
    name = module.many_names.az.storage_account_sub["am"].name
    ...
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sn" {
    name = module.many_names.az.storage_account_sub["sn"].name
    ...
}
```

and since the unkeyed details are always there, you could even just use the same module instance, depending on how these sub-naming conventions are set:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this" {
    name = module.names.az.storage_account.name
    ...
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "am" {
    name = module.names.az.storage_account_sub["am"].name
    ...
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sn" {
    name = module.names.az.storage_account_sub["sn"].name
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. In this answer the solution is to assign `az.storage` `null`, while the task is to get value of `az.storage.name` if `var.optional_descr.storage_account == null`

Comment: That's not what you showed in your response to my question about how you're using it, so I was working off that. Why does the name have to come from `az.storage.name`, rather than (say) `az.default_storage.name`? You're already going to need to have a conditional checking if `...storage_account == null`, so why not use that to pick the value out of a different variable?

Comment: The module generates names for `azrerm_` provider resource types. `az.storage_account.name` is a name of a storage resource returned. `az.function_app.name` is the name of a function app. If `optional_descr` parameter for `storage_account` is not setup, I need it's name returned az `az.storage_account.name`, if it is setup, the names will be returned as `az.storage_account["am"].name` and `az.storage_account["sn"].name`

Comment: Can you please update your question to show actual code of how you are using the output of this module? Also, what do `am`, `sn`, mean?

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I've updated the question

Comment: @AntonTeterine ok that helps a bit. Is it just the `storage_account` field that you want to be able to have sub-name-rules for, or all of the naming blocks? If it's all (or many) of them, are they configured by having other keys in the `optional_descr` map?

Comment: Ultimately, all. But since I have over 200 different fields, I've decided to 'support' few to start with. The values of `optional_descr.resource_type` if dynamic and not the same for each resource type when called. So I might have `storage_account = ["am", "sn"]` and `key_vault = ["f", "another", "master"]` etc.

Comment: Ok that's useful to know - might be good to update the question to show that. I'll update my answer shortly